# Views block doesn't show up at the user profile page

Tags: views, 8, users, blocks

I created a views block and try to make it appear on the user profile page. I did the following steps, but it doesn't show up:

1. Block layout -> Place block
2. Tab Pages: Select "Show for the listed pages and specify path: `/user/*`
3. Region: Footer

I tried different regions but can't make this block appear on profile page.

Additional info:

- I made a *Page view* with the exact same configuration and the same user can visualize it correctly. So it doesn't seem to be an issue with permissions.
- Other blocks do show up in the footer region, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the template.

Comment: Does it work with a regular block rather than a views block? Trying to narrow it down...

Comment: Yes, just tested with "powerd by Drupal" block and it shows up on profile page.

Comment: Can you confirm the `access: Permission` settings in the view (middle column)?

Comment: Are there Views settings that make the query not run, Contextual filters, did you add No results behavior?

Comment: @Prestosaurus `access: Permissions` was set to _View published content_, but changing it to _None_ doesn't make it appear neither. 
@prkos No results behavior is defined, their aren't any contextual filters nor queries.

Comment: How about your template files? Do you have a user template or preprocess function that could be overriding the page template for user pages? Maybe post a screenshot of your view? If you remove restrictions on the views block, does it then appear on the user pages as well as all pages?

Comment: View published content is correct, I would still check your user permissions at `/admin/people/permissions` just to make sure users can view the data your displaying..

Comment: @Prestosaurus The same user can visualize the same view duplicated as Page view. I use the default template for user pages.

Comment: Create a new views block with default settings/permissions and try to place on a region. Check if this works then set pages visibility.